# insert one data frame into another data frame by columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Sorry I did not find similar answer, if there were, from past posts here.

Suppose I have two simple n-by-m data frames, df1 and df2. Now I want to combine them to get a n-by-2m data frame called df. By doing this, I want column 1 in df2 to be column 2 in df, column 2 in df2 to be column 4 in df, column 3 in df2 to be column 6 in df....Meanwhile, column 1 in df1 is column 1 in df, column 2 in df1 is column 3 in df...

It means in the new df, column 1, 3, 5, 7...come from df1 and column 2, 4, 6, 8...come from df2.

In general, it looks like to INSERT df2 into df1 by every other column, to put each column of df2 behind its corresponding column in df1.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Maybe I am not clear enough, Suppose I have two data frames with the same # of rows, but one with column names V1 V2 V3, another with col names V4, V5, V6. If I combine them, the new data frame should have col names V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6, but I want the new data are arranged to be V1 V4 V2 V5 V3 V6, not V1 V3 V5 V2 V4 V6. Can you help generate such a sequence?

Answer (score 2):

why does it need to be that way, they are variables after all, but if you want to do it

```
m<-ncol(df1)
df<-merge(df1,df2)
df<-df[,c(seq(1,2*m, by=2),seq(2,2*m, by=2))
```

Comment: +1, but I think you left out the definition of `m` (and should it be 2m?).

Comment: @BrodieG, yes, it should be 2m, thanks for reminding

Comment: To simply put it, if i have 2n numbers from 1 to 2n, how can i generate a sequence arranged like 1, n+1, 2, n+2, 3, n+3, ... , n, 2n?

Comment: Thank you and @BrodieG, see my updates of the question, and I found the solution to generate a sequence arranged like 1, n+1, 2, n+2, 3, n+3, ... , n, 2n. say t=rep(c(1:n), each=2, times=1), h=rep(c(0, n), times=n), then t+h are what I want. Thank you so much anyway~